# Is there any invisible string character that can be ignored by "set fillchars", in the status line?

Tags: vimscript, neovim, statusline, string-manipulation

Currently, I'm trying to make a pretty minimal custom status line that suits my needs. One element of it, however, is a diagnostics report that depends on another plugin (coc.nvim). With a function, I can display this report on my status line conditionally, that is, only when there are errors in my code.

Although I can modify the string presented in my status bar when there are errors to report, I cannot set whitespaces, as I'm using line characters in `fillchars`. This does not seems to affect whitespaces set by `set statusline+=\` , however, I don't know how to include this command inside a string produced by another function.

As such, is there any special invisible character that can be set inside of a string, that could be ignored by `set fillchars`?

```
function! StatusDiagnostic() abort
  let info = get(b:, 'coc_diagnostic_info', {})
  if empty(info) | return '' | endif
  let msgs = []
  if get(info, 'error', 0)
    call add(msgs,'['. 'E' . info['error']  . ']'. ' ')
  endif
  if get(info, 'warning', 0)
    call add(msgs, '[' . 'W ' . info['warning'] . ']'. ' ')
  endif
  return join(msgs, ' '). '' . get(g:, 'coc_status', '')
endfunction

set fillchars=stl:─,stlnc:─
set laststatus=2
set statusline=
set statusline+=%m
set statusline+=\ 
set statusline+=%t
set statusline+=\ 
set statusline+=
set statusline+=\
set statusline+=%{StatusDiagnostic()}
set statusline+=%=
set statusline+=\ 
set statusline+=
set statusline+=\
set statusline+=%l
set statusline+=:
set statusline+=%L
set statusline+=\ 
set statusline+=
set statusline+=\
set statusline+=%P
```

Here is my status line:
[image: statusline with - instead of whitespace]
If I've failed to be clear, I want to put a whitespace after the closing bracket in `E1`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow; maybe you just don't want to adjust `fillchars`? But you could try a non-breaking space (0xA0, I think)

Comment: Also, welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Thank you for the welcome! A non-breaking space seems to be what I'm looking after. Any idea for how I should include that inside a string returned by the StatusDiagnostic() funcion?

Comment: Sure; change the spaces in your strings to the nbsp. For example, C-v `xA0` should work to insert it. Or C-k `NS`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ben is right :-| the solution is:

```
function! StatusDiagnostic() abort
  let info = get(b:, 'coc_diagnostic_info', {})
  if empty(info) | return '' | endif
  let msgs = []
  if get(info, 'error', 0)
    call add(msgs,'['. 'E' . info['error']  . ']'. "\<char 0xA0>")
  endif
  if get(info, 'warning', 0)
    call add(msgs, '[' . 'W ' . info['warning'] . ']'. "\<char 0xA0>")
  endif
  return join(msgs, "\<char 0xA0>"). '' . get(g:, 'coc_status', '')
endfunction
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, although your suggestion works for whitespaces set by  set statusline, they do not work inside of strings. I want to include a whitespace in the string returned by StatusDiagnostic(), that is ignored by fillchars.

Comment: Have you tried the second option with `set &statusline="Hello World "`? In my test it works even with `fillchars` set.

Comment: Yes, all whitespaces inside any string are being affected by fillchars, the only exception being whitespaces set with "set statusline=\ ". I've included your exemple without the "&" before "statusline=", however, since including your line with this character was not recognized.

Comment: And what if you use the form with the leading `&` (`set &statusline+=StatusDiagnostic()`)?

Comment: I can reproduce your problem and I confirm the problem is the `set statusline+=%{expr}` it replace any blank by the fillchar where the `let &statusline+=expr` does not.

Comment: `:set &statusline+=` is not valid. And `let &statusline+=func()` eliminates the OP's dynamic statusline behavior

Comment: You are right I realized late :-/

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, Smedt. The answer proposed by Knoble worked!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If the answer solve the problem I'll be glad if you could validate the solution using the v button next to the arrow buttons.